# Easiest formula to return percentage in a specific period

Tags: statistics

I have the following question in my homework.

> In Company K, employees who work during the day have an average salary
>   of 1500.00 and those who work at night, an average salary of 1100.00.
>   The average salary of the company is to 1,400.00. What will be the
>   percentage of employees who work during the day?

Which the easiest formula to return the result ?

Comment: If $p$ percent are day-workers, then $100-p$ percent are night-workers. It follows that the average salary is $\frac p{100}\cdot 1500 + \frac{100-p}{100}\cdot 1100$. By equating this with $1400$ you can solve for $p$.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, I tryied without success, I know that the result is 75%, but I didn't get this result. Strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If the fraction $p$ of the employees work during the day, $1-p$ work at night.  The overall average is then $1500p+1100(1-p)$

Comment: Thanks the hint, but unfortunately, I tryied without success, I know that the result is 75%, but I didn't get this result. Strange.

Comment: @Lucas_Santos:yes, 75% is correct.  The intuitive approach is that you need to go $\frac 14$ of the way from $1500$ to $1100$.  You can plug $p=0.75$ into this to verify, then follow through your work to find where it stops working to find the error.

Comment: It really really helps. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you apply the formula $1500p+1100(1-p)=1400$ subtract $1400p$ from both sides gives

$100p +1100(1-p)=1400(1-p) $ dividing by $1-p$ gives

$100 p/(1-p)+1100 = 1400$ or

$100 p/(1-p)=300$
so

$p/(1-p)=3$ or $ p=3-3p $ implying $ 4p=3$ and $p=3/4$ or $75%$.